# How can I refresh the Kendo UI grid in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid made with Angular 2 .It's part of a crud application ,where I have a delete button .After the delete I want the grid to refresh automatically.

This is the grid that shows the event's notifications :

```
<kendo-grid [data]="EventsNotificationSetup">

        <kendo-grid-command-column title="" width="200">
            <template >
                <button (click)="EditModal.open()" kendoGridEditCommand  kendoButton  [icon]="'pencil'">Edit</button>
                <button (click) = deleteEventNotification(dataItem.id) kendoGridRemoveCommand kendoButton [primary]="true"  [icon]="'trash'">Remove</button>


            </template>
        </kendo-grid-command-column>

        </kendo-grid>
```

This the delete code where I literally deleted the  record :

```
this._http.delete(this.link + notificationId,

            {
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                })
            })
            .map(res => res.json()).subscribe();
```

After this I made again an http.get to get the event notifications but it does not update automatically the grid,I have to refresh the page.

Do you know how can I refresh the grid?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old but were you ever able to find out how to refresh Angular2+ grid ?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove this item from EventsNotificationSetup in success handler of delete subscription and because of two-way data binding your grid will be updated as I remember correctly